# Put all changed files into a changelist in SVN

Tags: svn

How can i, after running `SVN status`, put all files into a changelist to save copying and pasting each individual one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can write a script to do this...

What platform are you on? Windows or Unix? What scripting language are you able to use?

Here's a real simple one I just did:

```
$ svn cl my-changelist $(svn st | awk '{print $2}')
```

It probably needs some work (what if I changed a property vs. a file or I changed both? What if I deleted a file?). But, it worked in my (admittedly simple) situation.

Answer (score 1):

awk's print $2 will fail if svn stat shows you flags like + or ~

cut might be safer, e.g.

```
svn st | cut -c9-
```

My bash-fu is not strong and the $() syntax didn't work for me. I ended up doing something like:

```
for i in `svn st | cut -c9-` do; svn changelist my-changelist $i; done
```

Comment: > for i in `svn st | cut -c9-` ; do svn changelist my-changelist $i; done

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have more than one changelists, you will want to filter out irrelevant lines first.

   ```
   svn status | grep '^[ADMRC]' | cut -c9- | xargs svn changelist foo
   ```
2. If you have file names with spaces, you will also need to use `eval`.

   ```
   eval "svn changelist foo $(svn status | grep '^[ADMRC]' | cut -c9- | sed 's/ /\\ /' | tr '\n' ' ')"
   ```

   `sed 's/ /\\ /'` escapes spaces.

Reference:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html